# Finding present values in a time frame, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time

I am working with a dataframe that has different products (each one with a different product reference, "PR" in this dataframe) that have a certain time frame in which they were working.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'PR':("1","2","3","4","5","18"),
    'StartDate':pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=6, freq='D'),
    'EndDate':np.random.choice( pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=365, 
                          freq='D'), 6, replace=False) 
    })
```

Which prints out this table

```
                PR  StartDate   EndDate
           0    1   2011-01-01  2011-03-01
           1    2   2011-01-02  2011-11-06
           2    3   2011-01-03  2011-01-10
           3    4   2011-01-04  2011-10-27
           4    5   2011-01-05  2011-08-31
           5    18  2011-01-06  2011-06-06
```

I want to find how many products are alive at any given month (In this case: (2011-01, 1 product alive), (2011-02, 5 products alive),(2011-04, 4 products alive), etc... How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for each month, if given product is within the `StartDate`, `EndDate` range.

```
In [26]: pd.Series(
            {dt: ((df.StartDate <= dt) & (df.EndDate >= dt)).sum()
             for dt in pd.date_range(start='2011-01-01', freq='1MS', periods=6)})
Out[26]:       
2011-01-01    1
2011-02-01    5
2011-03-01    5
2011-04-01    4
2011-05-01    4
2011-06-01    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks you! Absolutely what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
df.assign(dates = [pd.date_range(s,f, freq='MS') for s, f in zip(df['StartDate'], df['EndDate'])])\
  .explode('dates').groupby('dates')['PR'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
dates
2011-01-01    1
2011-02-01    5
2011-03-01    5
2011-04-01    4
2011-05-01    4
2011-06-01    4
2011-07-01    3
2011-08-01    3
2011-09-01    2
2011-10-01    2
2011-11-01    1
Name: PR, dtype: int64
```